# ImageButton not firing

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, events

I have the following button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEditInfo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/EditInformation.png" AlternateText="EditInformation" CommandName="EditDetails" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" OnClick="lnkEdit_Click" Enabled="true" />
```

I have the following method but looks like it is not hitting the method:

```
Protected Sub lnkEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Wondering if I am missing something. I put a breakpoint on the Protected Sub lnkEdit_Click but on click of the imagebutton I do not go there.

Comment: Have you searched on this site the numerous question posted on this specific problem? Look at the related column on the right. ->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working with `Data Controls` (GridView or DataList etc). To respond to the button/linkbutton/imagebutton events, you must have to handle the parent - [data control's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx) events.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your page it is hard to say. A couple things to check:

- Is the ImageButton inside a `<form  runat="server">`?
- Have you compared your page to the VB sample at [ImageButton Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx#Y10801) to see if anything might have been missed?